# Checking for a product before installing a plugin

Tags: windows, wix, installation

I am new to Windows Installer XML (WIX Toolset). I'm trying to figure out if my program was installed with its 32-bit version, or its 64-bit version. The only way for me to know that (with my little knowledge) is to do have these two properties (below) search in the program files directories and see if the program exists (I would check the registry, but the installer for this program does not use the windows registry).

```
<!--Check to see if ImageJ has been installed for 32-bit-->
<Property Id="IMAGEJINSTALLED32">
  <DirectorySearch Id="ProgramFilesSearch"
                   Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]"
                   AssignToProperty="no">
    <DirectorySearch Id="ImageJSearch" Path="ImageJ">
      <FileSearch Id="ImageJEXESearch" Name="ImageJ.exe" />
    </DirectorySearch>
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>

<!--Check to see if ImageJ has been installed for 64-bit-->
<Property Id="IMAGEJINSTALLED64">
  <DirectorySearch Id="ProgramFiles64Search"
                   Path="[ProgramFiles64Folder]"
                   AssignToProperty="no">
    <DirectorySearch Id="ImageJ64Search" Path="ImageJ">
      <FileSearch Id="ImageJEXE64Search" Name="ImageJ.exe" />
    </DirectorySearch>
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

Then check with these conditions

```
<!--Check for installation-->
<Condition Message="ImageJ is not installed for a 32-bit operating system. You have ImageJ installed with its 64-bit version. Please install this Plugin using the 64-bit version: (URL for 64-bit installer)">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR NOT IMAGEJINSTALLED64 OR IMAGEJINSTALLED32]]>
</Condition>
<Feature Id="CopyFiles" 
         Title="Plugin Installer for ImageJ" Level="1"
         Absent="disallow" AllowAdvertise="no">
  <!--Will run the necessary parts to install the plugin (by copying files to the right directory)-->
</Feature>
```

When I run this, it checks to see if ImageJ is ONLY installed in the 32-bit program files AND not in the 64-bit program files. If this check is true, then it would install the plugin. This is almost what I want.

What I really need to know is how I can handle these two conditions (along with the two I already have solved):
1) if the user has installed the program for both 32-bit AND 64-bit
2) if the user has not installed the program at all.

I have tried doing multiple conditions, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a file location to detect the application bitness can be buggy. This is because the application that will make the check will also have a bitness (that influences paths redirection), so from a 32 bit installer you will not be able to access 64-bit files paths, or the other way around.

A simpler method is to a make a [product code search](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/productsearch.html) (I assume you have two different installers, one for 32 and one for 64 bit machines). If you have two different installers than you should also have two unique [product codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thank you. That sounds much more simple. I looked up those links you gave. **Could you give an example of how to do this?** I am just not sure how to use the ProductSearch properly (because I wouldn't know what to put into either the ProductCode or UpgradeCode property - whichever one is chosen). Just so your aware, I did not create the Installer for this program. I  am simply creating this plugin installer. And yes, there are two different installers, so there would be two product codes. I just don't know how to find the product codes.

Comment: The productcode is GUID. You can get it from the installers if you open them with a tool like SuperOrca ( http://www.pantaray.com/msi_super_orca.html ). Just go to **Property** table and look for the row containing ProductCode.

Comment: WiX doesn't have a productcode search (and there isn't one in Windows Installer) although there is a util product code search. You could use an upgrade element to search for the upgradecode values (which should be different for different bitness) with an UpgradeVersion element that has OnlyDetect yes, setting a property if the UpgradeCode is detected.

Comment: It looks like the files for this program are EXE files. I used an EXE to MSI converter and found the productCode and UpgradeCode. For 32-bit and 64-bit, the codes are the same (same productCode, then same UpgradeCode). Is that common? (I imagine not) Would it be better for me to create a new installer, or any other suggestions?